# how to change background image according to weather

Tags: javascript

how to change background image according to weather. I used the code which someone mentioned in this site but it didn't worked please guide me. I did some changes but it didn't work please helppp. Here is my JavaScript code

```js
function backgroundChange(weather) {
  if (sky-cond == Rain) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/cac950bd-8f59-4376-8597-52366358d12e/d9wvf1t-b8eec3f5-b88b-4b1f-8aac-36bc21e06a92.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3sicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvY2FjOTUwYmQtOGY1OS00Mzc2LTg1OTctNTIzNjYzNThkMTJlXC9kOXd2ZjF0LWI4ZWVjM2Y1LWI4OGItNGIxZi04YWFjLTM2YmMyMWUwNmE5Mi5qcGcifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6ZmlsZS5kb3dubG9hZCJdfQ.WYDWFRtXw1BslrbVksftWlGdI6xCc0wHMhKMMx-NEuM')";
  } else if (weatherinfo == Clouds) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(cloud.gif)";
  } else if (sky-cond == Clear) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/panorama-sky-sunrise-sunset-beautiful-view-dark-blue-clouds-lit-by-bright-orange-yellow-sun-clear-sky-beauty-power-nature-meteorology-climate-changing-concept_127089-8097.jpg')";
  }else if (sky-cond == Haze) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Dark-Woods-HD-Wallpaper.jpg)";
  } else {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage= "url(background.gif)";
  }
}
```

Comment: sky-cond doesnt look like a valid variable name

Comment: sky kond is actually which shows clear sky,haze etc in our web page

Comment: Yes but you cant have a minus in a variable name

Comment: if you want, i can change and ask another question which such changes. I tried this also but it didnt work

Comment: so what should i do remove sky-cond?

Comment: Where do you get sky-cond from?

Comment: its a class for haze, clear sky,light rain like that

Comment: I saw from google

Answer (score 0):

something like that should work:

```js
function backgroundChange(weather) {
  if (weather === 'Rain') {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://sukhbinder.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/wpid-rain.jpg')";
  } else if (weather === 'Clouds') {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(cloud.gif)";
  } else if (weather === 'Clear') {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i...')";
  }else if (weather === 'Haze') {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://live.staticflickr.com/7192/6814624698_2a45c14996_n.jpg')";
  } else {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage= "url(background.gif)";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="backgroundChange('Rain')">rain</button>
<button onclick="backgroundChange('Haze')">haze</button>
```

the paramter `weather` should contain your `skyCond` variable as a String. as @PizzaDownload said the dash in your name is invalid.

Be aware that with the strict comparison `===` the upper and lower case plays a role.

Comment: what happens if you call your function with `backgroundChange('Haze')`? then the comparison should work. - I have added a demo to show you what I mean.

Comment: i dont want this function on onclick i want that it sees my weather displayed and then change the background image according to the weather

Comment: nothing happens on backgroundChange('Haze')

Comment: It's just a working demo. You can add the function whereever you want. Please share and update your main question with your code - so we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
backgroundChange("Clear"); // Can change the parameter to check different climates

public backgroundChange(weather) {
    if (weather == "Rain") {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage =
        "url('https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/cac950bd-8f59-4376-8597-52366358d12e/d9wvf1t-b8eec3f5-b88b-4b1f-8aac-36bc21e06a92.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3sicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvY2FjOTUwYmQtOGY1OS00Mzc2LTg1OTctNTIzNjYzNThkMTJlXC9kOXd2ZjF0LWI4ZWVjM2Y1LWI4OGItNGIxZi04YWFjLTM2YmMyMWUwNmE5Mi5qcGcifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6ZmlsZS5kb3dubG9hZCJdfQ.WYDWFRtXw1BslrbVksftWlGdI6xCc0wHMhKMMx-NEuM')";
    } else if (weather == "Clouds") {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(cloud.gif)"; // give proper url for the image or gif here
    } else if (weather == "Clear") {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage =
        "url('https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/panorama-sky-sunrise-sunset-beautiful-view-dark-blue-clouds-lit-by-bright-orange-yellow-sun-clear-sky-beauty-power-nature-meteorology-climate-changing-concept_127089-8097.jpg')";
    } else if (weather == "Haze") {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage =
        "url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Dark-Woods-HD-Wallpaper.jpg)";
    } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(background.gif)";  // give proper url for the image or gif here
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your response but it is not working

Comment: Check this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-m6gmxa